# Two ListView Side By Side

Tags: android, listview

I have two ListView. And I need to place them side by side horizontally. But the problem is - Only one list is visible. (Note : The second list is in right side of the layout and can have at most 1 character. And the first list will expand to fill the rest of the screen.)

Help me please.

The layout is like this.

```
------------
|       |  |
|       |  |
|       |  |
|       |  |
|       |  |
|       |  |
|       |  |
|       |  |
|       |  |
------------
```

---

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Shaiful

Comment: For this take first listview widh as wrapp copntent or 100 dip like that

Comment: Did it help, is it working now for you? People will keep helping you if you keep your questions updated and give some feedback!

Comment: The Actual status is, I remove one list. :)

Answer (score 6):

I can't believe nobody has come up with this in three years. Perhaps somebody else will have this question.

The issue is that ListView is greedy when it comes to horizontal space. You can tell it to pipe down using `layout_width='0dp'` and whichever `layout_weight` numbers you feel are best. Below is an example putting `leftListView` at ¾ and `rightListView` at ¼. I tried it, it works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/leftListView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight=".75" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/rightListView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Another alternative is to so the same layout trick but with FrameLayouts, then create fragments for each ListView. It's heavier but you might find value in having the Fragments lying around.

Answer (score 5):

I think use this code it will work fine.
You have to use layout_weight = 0.5 and things will work perfectly fine.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/sportsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/sports_array"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/sportsList_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/sports_array"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So, basically use two list views in a linear layout and give the weight of each layout to 0.5 . I think this helps.

Comment: How is this different from my answer, posted more than a year ago?

Comment: @QED his answer doesn't mention that you have to set the width (or height depending on your orientation) to 0px. 
Is a big omission to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a `LinearLayout` with attribute `android:orientation="horizontal"`
Then put **2** `LinearLayouts` with  `android:orientation="vertical"` into the horizontal one.
Now fill the vertical once with your stuff.

For futher information look [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html) :)

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**
Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="75dp">
 <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1">

**YOUR STUFF**

 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     android:layout_weight="2">

 **YOUR STUFF**

 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I already did this before post this comment. And It's not working. The second list fully overlap the first list. :(

Answer (score 1):

Your first LinearLayout says fill_parent for both height and width, so it will take up all the room.  Instead, use a single LinearLayout that is set to horizontal, then put your two ListViews inside there.  The height should be wrap_content.  The width can be set however you want (not fill_parent though), and you can use minWidth and layout_weight to specify better.

Comment: Ok. First of all, Thanks for reply. This is not the full layout. This is only a part of layout(where i define two list side by side). As i mention in my question the second list contain at most 1 character. I used layout_width="wrap_content" in the second list to wrap to its width. And I used layout_width="fill_parent" & layout_weight="1" to fill all the remaining space after fill the second list. Do you please explain, why I shouldn't use fill_parent?

Comment: fill_parent on width means "match my width to my parent's width minus padding."  When you do that for width, you're saying that nothing else should be to either side of the View (within that View's parent).  You can also look at the hierarchyviewer to get an idea of why your layouts are displaying how they are.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a relative layout or table layout as the root layout and then positioning the 2 listviews as children of the root.

Comment: relative layout is one of the worst thing you can do, to support various devices

Answer (score 0):

Put the two in a horizontal LinearLayout, like several have suggested. For the list on the left, set the layout_width to 0 and layout_weight to 1; for the list on the right, set layout_width to wrap_content and layout_weight to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <ListView

            android:id="@+id/list_view2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="475dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="306dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd`enter code here`="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok. I see that thread is dead, but i know how to do that.

My layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListView01"
            android:layout_width="192px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        </RelativeLayout>


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListView02"
            android:layout_width="192px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Second my code from activity:

```
 @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);    
        ListView lv1=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.ListView01);  
        ListView lv2=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.ListView02);
        File fCurrDirOne = new File ("/");
        File fCurrDirTwo = new File ("/");
        String[] mListOfFilesOne = fCurrDirOne.list();
        String[] mListOfFilesTwo = fCurrDirTwo.list();
        ArrayAdapter list1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(          
                this, R.layout.itemlistview,mListOfFilesOne);  
        ArrayAdapter list2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(          
                this, R.layout.itemlistview,mListOfFilesTwo);  
        lv1.setAdapter(list1);  
        lv2.setAdapter(list2);  
    }
```

Enjoy)

P.S. you should create layuot for you list items, mine called itemlistview.xml, and you can use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 as default.

My itemlistview.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp" >

</TextView>
```